# `sizeof` struct in union definition

Tags: c, struct, unions, c11

To access a `struct` byte-wise, I'm using a `union`.

```
typedef struct {
    char hi;
    char lo;
} range;

union {
    range by_name;
    char as_bytes[sizeof(range)];
} U1;

char use_U1(void){
    char c = U1.as_bytes[0];
    return U1.by_name.hi;
}
```

**Question 1:** Is it possible to skip the `typedef`? Like this:

```
union {
    struct {
        char hi;
        char lo;
    } by_name;
    char as_bytes[2]; //want sizeof()
} U2;
```

A naive `char as_bytes[sizeof(by_name)]` doesn't compile:
error: 'by_name' undeclared here (not in a function)

**Question 2:** Same but with anonymous structure, to avoid typing `.by_name` when using.

```
union {
    struct {
        char hi;
        char lo;
    };
    char as_bytes[2]; //want sizeof()
} U3;

int use_U3(void){
    char c = U3.as_bytes[0];
    return U3.hi; // anonymous structure
}
```

Read so far: [union](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/union), [struct](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct)

Comment: Why are you using a union instead of just casting the address to `char *`? (Tangential to the question itself)

Comment: @MadPhysicist, that's just a short fake example. Real struct is much longer.

Comment: Wouldn't that make a `char *` cast all the more attractive?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with typing out 2 in the array size in this case. 2 bytes will always have size 2. Any padding present will be handled by the union and trail after those 2 bytes.

Comment: in general, it is a poor programming practice to use Anonymous structs and unions.  This is (for several reasons including) most debuggers cannot display the individual fields without a 'tag' name.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I'm probably brainwashed about possible harms of casts. I used to think about it as asking compiler to step aside and keep calm with its annoying checks. So I'd like to give a try to something without casting.

Comment: @Xpector. If I'm not mistaken, there are a couple of types of casts that are actually always guaranteed to work, and `char *` is one of them. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @MadPhysicist You can go from struct to char pointer, but not the other way around. So it is less flexible.

Comment: Though notably, using "sloppy typing" `char` for storing raw binary data is a horrible idea, because of the implementation-defined signedness. Professional code always uses `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot take the size of an an anonymous type, so simply make it not anonymous:

```
union 
{
    struct range// <<< give it a tag here
    { 
        char hi;
        char lo;
    } by_name;

    char as_bytes[sizeof(struct range)]; // <<< Take sizeof here

} U2;
```

You can also create a nested typedef, though it serves little purpose perhaps:

```
union 
{
    typedef struct 
    {
        char hi;
        char lo;
    } range ; 

    range by_name;

    char as_bytes[sizeof(range)];
} U2;
```

Comment: The little purpose of a nested typedef could be to limit the scope of the `range`, I think.  Useful in my case.

Comment: @Xpector The first non-typdef has that same advantage. My point was merely that there was little purpose in creating a typedef alias just to avoid typing 'struct' given the limited scope, and the fact that it appears only once.  Possibly if there were other members using the same type.

Answer (score 3):

You can give the `struct` a tag name and use that.

```
union {
    struct inner {
        char hi;
        char lo;
    } by_name;
    char as_bytes[sizeof(struct inner)];
} U2;
```

Note that this does require that the inner struct has a name.  If there's no name, the tag must be omitted.

Comment: You can make it anonymous and satisfy the question’s request to avoid `typedef` by repeating the structure definition: `union { struct { char hi; char lo; }; char as_bytes[sizeof(struct { char hi; char lo; })]; } U2;`. I think they might prefer to repeat the `typedef`, though. 

Answer (score 1):

More simple version not portable (if you plan to use non gcc or mvsc compilers):

```
union {
    struct{
        char hi;
        char lo;
    };
    char as_bytes[0];
} U2;
```